# Quais as linguagens de programação que dão suporte a Linux e Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, característica-linguagem, sistema-operacional

A questão já esta no título, contudo para deixar mais claro:

- Quais as linguagens em que eu escrevo um único código, e rode tanto em Linux como Windows?

#### Exemplo

- `C`. Exceto alguns comandos como `system("cls"); system("clear");`.
- `Java`. Maquina Virtual para interpretar.

#### Obs

- Linguagens que executem alguma tarefa ou janela no sistema operacional.

Comment: Acho que a pergunta está um pouco ampla. Apenas pela pergunta, php, javascript também serviriam como resposta, mesmo sendo web, até C#.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Essencialmente todas. Na verdade, é uma exceção ter linguagens que rodem apenas em um deles e não no outro, em geral linguagens pouco conhecidas. A maior exceção talvez seja o Delphi. Mesmo assim é possível usar o Lazarus que usa linguagem quase idêntica, mas que exige muitas mudanças em vários casos.

A linguagem em si tem pouco a ver com o sistema operacional. Ela pode ter mais restrição no processador que roda, já que a linguagem ou precisa gerar um código nativo para um processador específico ou precisa ter um interpretador ou máquina virtual para aquele processador. Existem algumas linguagens que confundem sua estrutura básica com o que deveria ser biblioteca. Aí obviamente complica mais.

## Biblioteca

Claro que a biblioteca básica da linguagem precisa ser capaz de realizar certas operações que dependem do sistema operacional. Quase todas possuem abstrações ou pelo menos bibliotecas específicas que permitem fazer todas as principais tarefas nos dois sistemas operacionais. Eventualmente será necessário fazer alguma adaptação para as especificidades. As bibliotecas que conseguem abstrair 100% usam um método de "mínimo denominador comum",  que não dá bons resultados.

Algumas se destacam mais por possuírem melhores abstrações e uma quantidade maior de APIs atendidas, sejam na biblioteca padrão ou bibliotecas reconhecidas que se tornam quase padrão. C e C++ com algumas bibliotecas específicas são conhecidas por atenderem muito bem ambos.

## Implementações

Linguagens interpretadas e rodando em máquinas virtuais costumam ir muito bem também nos dois, isto inclui C#, VB.NET, Java, PHP, Python, Ruby, Perl, JS, Lua, só para ficar nas mais conhecidas. O que importa é ter o ambiente onde elas rodam funcionando bem nos dois sistemas operacionais.

Há uma certa subjetividade em qual atende melhor as duas plataformas ao mesmo tempo. Mas todo código que pretende rodar em mais do que uma plataforma precisa ser escrito pensando nisto.

Note que estamos falando de [implementações](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111284/101) de linguagens porque duvido que alguém faça uma linguagem que seja especificada para rodar em uma só plataforma, não faz sentido.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Foi o que pensei de imediato, praticamente todas as modernas.

Comment: Muito bom, creio que a frase que mais se destaca "Todo código que pretende rodar em mais do que uma plataforma precisa ser escrito pensando nisto."

Comment: Delphi é em cima de Object Pascal, que [tem suporte a Linux](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Kylix).

Comment: Ainda estão dando manutenção para o Kylix?

Comment: @GiancarloAbelGiulian não, há muitos anos. Na verdade nunca foi dado suporte de fato, nunca funcionou como deveria e como ninguém usava, foi abandonado logo em seguida. De qualquer forma, apesar de ter uma base de linguagem igual, as aplicações não conseguiam ser reaproveitadas de fato, precisava de todo um retrabalho.