# Especificação e Implementação

Tags: terminologia, engenharia-de-software

Comumente vejo as palavras "especificação" e "implementação", mas não sei a diferença entre uma e outra. Por exemplo:

> É possível ter controle sobre o coletor de lixo, isto apenas não ocorre com o Java na sua implementação padrão, até onde eu sei, também por força de especificação.

No geral, o que é implementação e o que é especificação?

Comment: No contexto geral ou no contexto do java/coletor de lixo?

Comment: No geral, usei o coletor de lixo como exemplo.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## [Especificação](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_(technical_standard)#Information_technology)

É algo abstrato. É algum "documento" que estabelece regras a serem seguidas, o que se espera das possíveis implementações. Essas regras podem exigir algumas coisas e proibir outras. É uma formalização de como algo deve proceder. É a lei. Grosso modo, é a receita.

## [Implementação](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implementation)

É algo concreto. É como é feito de verdade. É o que existe para ser usado. É a aplicação da lei. É o bolo feito por alguém atendendo o que diz a receita.

É possível variar a receita, mas se modificar pontos fundamentais dela, estará ferindo o prato e ele não pode mais receber aquele nome. Obviamente que na culinária causa menos problema que na computação :P.

## Relação entre elas

É óbvio que se a implementação não faz algo que a especificação obriga ter, quem for usar aquilo, que deve ser um padrão, terá problemas. Se a implementação faz algo extra que a especificação não proíbe não haverá problemas. Mas se for usar o que foi criado em cima desta implementação aproveitando os extras, obviamente não poderá portar para uma implementação diferente que se atenha mais restritamente à especificação.

No contexto descrito a implementação está sendo feita em cima da especificação, atendendo todas as regras estabelecidas por ela. A implementação pode, em tese, fazer qualquer coisa que não esteja proibida pela especificação, mas isso pode trazer dificuldades, até futuras em uma revisão da especificação.

Dentro das regras a implementação pode e deve fazer o melhor possível para atender as necessidades dos seus usuários.

Se a implementação ferir uma regra da especificação ela não poderá ser considerada como aderente àquele padrão.

A especificação pode ser mais detalhada ou mais superficial, dando mais rigidez ou flexibilidade ao que a implementação pode fazer. Também pode dar mais ambiguidade e trazer problemas. Especificação pode ter *bug* :).

Costuma ser mais difícil fazer uma boa especificação do que uma boa implementação, ainda que a quantidade de trabalho possa ser o inverso.

Uma especificação ruim pode dificultar ou até inviabilizar uma boa implementação existir.

Normalmente a especificação deve ser simples de entender. A implementação deve ser boa de usar.

Alguns domínios funcionam melhor com uma especificação clara e formal existente. Outros podem ser só um complicador desnecessário e indesejável.

Planejar como vai implementar não é especificação, pelo menos não no sentido descrito.

Algumas implementações são consideradas como especificação. São especificações informais e outras implementações devem ser compatíveis com esta, até os *bugs*, porque não há clareza quando é um *bug* e quando não é. Há prós e contras de se fazer isto.

[Especificação para linguagem de programação](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language_specification).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 10):

Quando várias empresas produzem produtos similares, algum orgão/instituto ou mesmo grupo de empresas se reunem para definir recomendações ou padrões
que devem ser seguidos por aquelas empresas afim de reduzir incompatibilidades. Um documento é criado contendo todas essas recomendações com o objetivo de

- Criar um vocabulário unificado.
- Definir protocolos de comunicação/integração.

Exemplos de especifições: O modelo OSI de rede, o padrão ANSI SQL, especificação da JVM.

A implementação é o resultado aplicado (concreto) de uma especificação, por motivos técnicos, de desempenho ou de utilização a implementação
pode ser totalmente diferente da especificação.

Exemplos de implementações: protocolo TCP/IP, MySQL, SQL Server, A JVM da oracle a Open JVM.

O Modelo ISO/OSI definir como funciona a troca de mensagens entre hosts, possui 7 camadas, cada uma cuida de uma parte do trabalho são elas, física, enlace, rede, transporte, sessão, apresentação e aplicação.

O protocolo TCP/IP foi baseado na especificação OSI, porém por motivos técnicos possui apenas 4 camadas, enlace, rede transporte e aplicação. Praticamente a primeira camada, enlace do TCP/IP faz o trabalho da camada física e de enlace do modelo OSI, isso é uma exemplo de como uma implementação pode mudar bastante da especificação.

Answer (score 8):

Você já teve respostas úteis, mas como esse tipo de dúvida é recorrente (isto é, pode aparecer novamente no futuro com outros termos), vale a dica de que os dicionários são muito úteis. Se você consultar os termos verá que:

**Especificação**:

ato ou efeito de especificar; discriminação, pormenorização
descrição e/ou enumeração exaustiva e minuciosa das características de determinado conjunto de coisas, de um projeto etc

(Grande Dicionário Houaiss da língua portuguesa)

Ato de especificar

1. Determinar por espécies.
2. Indicar a espécie de.
3. Particularizar.
4. Explicar pormenorizadamente.
5. Mencionar por partes.

(Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa)

**Implementação**:

ato ou efeito de implementar

(Grande Dicionário Houaiss da língua portuguesa)

.Ato ou efeito de implementar.

1. Pôr em prática, em execução ou assegurar a realização de (alguma coisa). = EXECUTAR
2. [Informática]  Instalar, pôr em funcionamento (programa ou componente informático).

(Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa)

Fontes:

- [Grande Dicionário Houaiss da língua portuguesa](http://houaiss.uol.com.br/)
- [Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa](https://www.priberam.pt)