# Qual a linguagem utilizada para programar um sistema operacional?

Tags: windows, sistema-operacional

Qual a linguagem utilizada na programação de um SO?

Comment: Muito Ampla a pergunta. Quer saber apenas do Windows ou de alguma distribuição do Linux também?

Comment: Os principais amigo

Comment: O do MSX é feito grande parte diretamente no código de máquina mesmo, outras partes em assembly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Essencialmente qualquer uma que desejar. De uma certa forma é possível escrever um sistema operacional não convencional até com JS, embora seja uma linguagem péssima para isso e haverá fortes limitações. Já há OSes escritos em [Lua](http://www.lua.org/) ([aqui](https://outofhanwell.wordpress.com/2008/08/16/khoros-a-lua-operating-system/) e [aqui](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=3872068)).

Alguns foram escritos em C#: ([Singularity](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/singularity/), [COSMOS](https://github.com/CosmosOS/Cosmos), [SharpOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SharpOS_(operating_system)), [Midori](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midori_(operating_system))). [Outros em Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaOS). Enfim, qualquer linguagem pode ser usada para escrever um OS. Eu poderia sair listando OSes em praticamente cada uma das linguagens *mainstream* e até mesmo em outras de nicho. Isso pode ser [lido aqui](http://wiki.osdev.org/Languages).

Linguagens de programação possuem a capacidade de executar qualquer tarefa. Suas implementações podem limitar um pouco o que elas podem acessar no *hardware* onde vão rodar.

Claro que algumas linguagens são mais adequadas. Por isso C é muito usada para isso. C++ também vem sendo usada com sucesso cada vez mais. Assembly dominava esse tipo de desenvolvimento por muito tempo e ainda há casos assim.

O Windows é essencialmente escrito em C (não vou postar aqui por motivos óbvios, mas a internet "disponibiliza" os fontes de uma versão antiga dele). Muitas APIs e serviços extras são escritos ou adaptados para C++. Claro que possui algumas pequenas partes em Assembly, é difícil que não exista pelo menos um pequeno trecho de um OS que não seja. Softwares agregados podem eventualmente ser escritos em outras linguagens, mas duvido que possam ser considerados partes do OS.

A [implementação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111284/101) da linguagem pode ser mais importante para definir se dá para escrever um OS do que a linguagem especificada.

Leitura complementar:

- [O que caracteriza uma linguagem de programação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102452/101)
- [O que é linguagem de programação, IDE e compilador?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Muito obrigado por compartilhar seu conhecimento comigo e com todos do StackOverflow, tirou todas as dúvidas possíveis.

Comment: "não vou postar aqui por motivos óbvios". Poderia explicar?

Comment: Porque seria pirataria.

Answer (score 3):

No caso do Windows é  C, C++, C# e algumas coisas em assembly segundo a própria microsoft. Linux é só pegar o código da distribuição na internet e olhar. A maioria utiliza muito C, C++ e assembly pra coisas que precisam ser muito otimizadas.

Answer (score 0):

Atualmente os sistemas operacionais "de produção" são escritos em C.

Comment: Todos eles? tem certeza? O que seria "de produção"?

Comment: Windows, Linux, UNIXes em geral (incluindo BSDs)....mainframes IBM possuem sistemas operacionais escritos em assembly, mas de modo geral acho que estão em regime de manutenção, não de evolução...deve haver sistemas real-time/embarcados escritos em assembly....os sistemas "de produção" que considero são uma questão de opinião, claro, por isso as aspas, mas na prática, atualmente escrever um sistema operacional em outra linguagem que não C é algo um tanto exótico

Comment: Tá explicado, mas cada vez se usa menos C e mais outras linguagens para escrever SOs, logo C talvez seja considerada exótica para isso :)

Comment: Logo ? How soon is soon ? :) Pra mim esse "logo" vai ser algumas dezenas de anos ainda....

Comment: Como grande parte do SOs novos já são escritos em outras linguagens, de uma certa forma já está acontecendo

Answer (score -5):

A linguagem C foi desenvolvida para criar sistemas operacionais de modo a facilitar o o processo do programador ( para nao ter que ficar  usando assembly). Hoje em dia ainda é usado "C"

Comment: porque apenas minhas resposta esta ganhando "-" . Exijo um feed Back... minha reputação esta caindo e atrapalhando minha interação

Comment: Quanto as outras ainda não sei mas essa publicação pode ser considerada de  baixa qualidade, é um comentário que não responde a pergunta feita na página. Está equivocado, C é uma linguagem de multipropósito e foi concebido em 1972, por Dennis Ritchie e Ken Thompson, com o intuito de criar ferramentas para o sistema operacional UNIX. Só para constar o UNIX foi desenvolvido em 1970 escrito em assembly, somente em 1973 saiu a primeira versão, System4, escrita em C.

Comment: @AugustoVasques igual você disse "Foi criada em 1972 por Dennis Ritchie para ser usada no desenvolvimento sistema operacional Unix"  Não disse que sempre foi utilizado C mas que a criação do C teve como objetivo a criação de SOs