# A estrutura std::map em C++ é uma árvore?

Tags: c++, estrutura-de-dados

Eu sei que cada elemento da estrutura é representado por uma chave e um dado, mas não o vejo como sendo uma árvore, e li em algum lugar que é uma arvore.

Comment: Seria interessante postar onde leu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É bem provável que o [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) seja feito com uma árvore. Não há garantias.

A [especificação não diz como ele deve ser implementado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111284/101) e nem deveria mesmo determinar detalhe de implementação. É função da especificação dizer que garantias públicas uma implementação deva dar e mais nada. Cada implementação deve ter a liberdade de fazer como achar melhor.

Quando vai usar uma mapa interessa apenas que ele é um mapa, ou seja, é uma coleção de dados com pares de chave e valor ordenadas pela chave.

Se você se prender à implementação pode ter problemas quando ela não estiver disponível.

Uma árvore é uma boa implementação para esse problema porque é a forma que costuma funcionar melhor para elementos que podem ser inseridos em qualquer ordem e o acesso deva ser de forma classificada. Existem diversas variações de árvores possíveis que cada implementador pode escolher.

Um [exemplo de implementação](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-3.4/stl__map_8h-source.html).

Tem um [artigo que fala que a implementação originalmente usada na STL](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/stls-red-black-trees/184410531) é a [Red Black Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree). É bastante provável que as bibliotecas modernas usam variações disso.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 2):

A definição do C++ não especifica como deve ser feita a implementação. No entanto, a implementação mais comum parece ser uma "red black tree".

Artigo no Stackoverflow em inglês sobre o assunto:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288320/why-is-stdmap-implemented-as-a-red-black-tree

Answer (score 2):

Sim, geralmente implementações de MAPs são feitas utilizando arvores binárias de busca(não apenas no c++).
Inclusive no site http://www.cplusplus.com/ tem boas referências, e la tem esse pequeno comentário sobre o std::map:

> Maps are typically implemented as binary search trees.[Link do MAP](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/)