# Qual é a relação entre DER e banco de dados relacionais?

Tags: banco-de-dados, terminologia, engenharia-de-software, entidade-relacionamento, der

Qual é a relação entre DER e banco de dados relacionais?

Comment: [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/)

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 5):

DER ou Diagrama Entidade-Relacionamento, como o próprio nome diz, é uma representação gráfica das entidades necessárias em um modelo de dados e seus relacionamentos, portanto é uma forma abstrata.

Bancos de dados relacionais são os mecanismos que concretizam essas representações e produzem uma base de dados com essas entidades e possuem facilidades que permitem que elas sejam acessadas de forma relacionada.

Justamente por ambos terem como base o relacionamento dos dados eles se encaixam bem.

É comum dizermos que o DER é usado para criar um modelo lógico e o banco de dados é o modelo físico. É um pouco mais complicado que isso, mas é uma forma simplificada de entender.

O banco de dados é a [implementação do que foi especificado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111284/101) no DER.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: muito obrigado!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 4):

Um [modelo entidade relacionamento (MER)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modelo_entidade_relacionamento) descreve os objetos (entidades) envolvidos em um domínio de negócios, com suas características (atributos) e como elas se relacionam entre si (relacionamentos). Esse modelo conceitual é representado graficamente pelo diagrama de entidade relacionamento (ER ou DER). Esse diagrama facilita a comunicação entre os integrantes da equipe, pois oferece uma linguagem comum utilizada tanto pelo analista, responsável por levantar os requisitos, e os desenvolvedores, responsáveis por implementar aquilo que foi modelado.

Já um [banco de dados relacional](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banco_de_dados_relacional) modela os dados de uma forma que eles sejam percebidos pelo usuário como tabelas, ou mais formalmente relações. A linguagem padrão dos Bancos de Dados Relacionais é a *Structured Query Language*, ou simplesmente SQL, como é mais conhecida.

A relação entre DER e banco de dados relacionais é que um modelo ER é normalmente implementado como um banco de dados. Nos casos de um banco de dados relacional, que armazena dados em tabelas, as próprias tabelas representam as entidades. Alguns campos de dados nestas tabelas apontam para índices em outras tabelas, que representam relacionamentos.

Answer (score 0):

O DER é o diagrama  de entidades e relacionamentos ou seja você vai mostrar a parte dele como as entidades(tabelas) do seu banco de dados estão relacionadas seria uma forma logica de representar esse relacionamento, e o banco de dados relacional uma forma física.

De forma geral no DER você coloca varias entidades se relacionando, por exemplo tabela produto com a fornecedor, produto podendo ter apenas um fornecedor e o fornecedor varias coisas, o modelo relacional é a mesma coisa, só que com sua aplicação direta no banco de dados já, através das chaves primárias e estrangeiras.