# O que é Backus-Naur Form (BNF)?

Tags: terminologia, projeto-de-compiladores

Estava lendo uma resposta aqui e me deparei com esse termo, então o que significa esse termo, e qual a relação/influência nas linguagens atuais?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

É uma notação para expressar gramáticas livres de contexto. Em geral é usada em gramáticas de linguagens de programação. Mas também é usada para expressar protocolos de comunicação, formato de dados, outros tipos de linguagens, etc. Não costuma ser usado em língua natural porque essa notação não é adequada para gramáticas que dependem de contexto.

De uma certa forma podemos dizer que é uma linguagem para escrever linguagens ([especificação, não implementação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111284/101) da linguagem).

Ela demonstra como os [*tokens*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token) podem ser usados de forma válida no texto que será produzido com aquela linguagem ou formato.

Ela tem algumas regras que indicam quais caracteres são aceitos, que são os *tokens* mais básicos e dá-se um nome para cada grupo desses caracteres. Também pode ser expresso como esses *tokens* podem ser compostos para formar outros *tokens*, e assim por diante. Na verdade, em geral é expresso o contrário, os *tokens* mais complexos são expressos primeiro e cada componente desse *token* é expresso depois.

A notação permite dizer quais são as sequências de *tokens* válidos, se ele pode ser repetido ou não, ou até omitido, ou ainda se existe alternativas de uso. Geralmente permite recursão no uso de *tokens*. Obviamente que para isso precisa expressar de uma forma que a recursão não seja infinita, através da alternativa.

Veja um exemplo que é legal porque a própria notação BNF pode ser expressa em BNF, conforme [artigo da Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form):

```
 <syntax>         ::= <rule> | <rule> <syntax>
 <rule>           ::= <opt-whitespace> "<" <rule-name> ">" <opt-whitespace> "::=" <opt-whitespace> <expression> <line-end>
 <opt-whitespace> ::= " " <opt-whitespace> | ""
 <expression>     ::= <list> | <list> <opt-whitespace> "|" <opt-whitespace> <expression>
 <line-end>       ::= <opt-whitespace> <EOL> | <line-end> <line-end>
 <list>           ::= <term> | <term> <opt-whitespace> <list>
 <term>           ::= <literal> | "<" <rule-name> ">"
 <literal>        ::= '"' <text1> '"' | "'" <text2> "'"
 <text1>          ::= "" | <character1> <text1>
 <text2>          ::= "" | <character2> <text2>
 <character>      ::= <letter> | <digit> | <symbol>
 <letter>         ::= "A" | "B" | "C" | "D" | "E" | "F" | "G" | "H" | "I" | "J" | "K" | "L" | "M" | "N" | "O" | "P" | "Q" | "R" | "S" | "T" | "U" | "V" | "W" | "X" | "Y" | "Z" | "a" | "b" | "c" | "d" | "e" | "f" | "g" | "h" | "i" | "j" | "k" | "l" | "m" | "n" | "o" | "p" | "q" | "r" | "s" | "t" | "u" | "v" | "w" | "x" | "y" | "z"
 <digit>          ::= "0" | "1" | "2" | "3" | "4" | "5" | "6" | "7" | "8" | "9"
 <symbol>         ::=  "|" | " " | "-" | "!" | "#" | "$" | "%" | "&" | "(" | ")" | "*" | "+" | "," | "-" | "." | "/" | ":" | ";" | "<" | "=" | ">" | "?" | "@" | "[" | "\" | "]" | "^" | "_" | "`" | "{" | "|" | "}" | "~"
 <character1>     ::= <character> | "'"
 <character2>     ::= <character> | '"'
 <rule-name>      ::= <letter> | <rule-name> <rule-char>
 <rule-char>      ::= <letter> | <digit> | "-"
```

Aí o *token* `<syntax>` pode ser composto por um `<rule>`, **OU** por um conjunto de `<rule>` seguido de um `<syntax>` (notou a recursão?).

Para saber como é composto o `<rule>`, está embaixo. Para saber como é composto cada um dos seus elementos, vai olhando cada regra BNF listada.

Alguns são terminadores, ou seja, não tem mais o que olhar. É o caso, nesse exemplo de `<letter>`, `<digit>` e `<symbol>`. Terminadores também são usados opcionalmente em outras regras.

Existem extensões da notação para expressar melhor algumas situações.

[EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) de uma [versão da EcmaScript](https://github.com/highsource/javascript-codemodel/blob/master/parser/src/main/javacc/ecmascript-262.jj).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 3):

[BNF](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formalismo_de_Backus-Naur) (Backus-Naur Form), foi originalmente criada por John Backus e Peter Naur, é uma metassintaxe usada para expressar [gramáticas livres de contexto](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%C3%A1tica_livre_de_contexto). Com ela, é possível especificar quais sequências de símbolos constituem um programa sintaticamente válido em um determinado idioma.

A relação/influência nas linguagens de programação é que a BNF foi inicialmente desenvolvida para especificar e documentar a linguagem Algol 60. Posteriormente, foi utilizada para definição de várias linguagens incluindo C, Pascal e Ada.

O blog iMaster, tem um artigo interessante sobre o assunto: [O que é BNF e por que os desenvolvedores devem ser importar?](http://imasters.com.br/artigo/22680/desenvolvimento/o-que-e-bnf-e-por-que-os-desenvolvedores-devem-ser-importar/)