# O que é e como funciona a análise sintática ascendente e descendente?

Tags: compiladores

De acordo com algumas pesquisas que fiz, a Análise Sintática na computação, [conhecido como *parsing*](https://techterms.com/definition/parse) em inglês, é o processo de analisar uma sequência de entrada (lida de um arquivo de computador ou do teclado, por exemplo) para determinar sua estrutura gramatical segundo uma determinada [gramática formal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/178720/o-que-%C3%A9-backus-naur-form-bnf#178778).

> A análise sintática transforma um texto na entrada em uma estrutura de
>   dados, em geral uma árvore, o que é conveniente para processamento
>   posterior e captura a hierarquia implícita desta entrada. Através da
>   análise léxica é obtido um grupo de tokens, para que o analisador
>   sintático use um conjunto de regras para construir uma árvore
>   sintática da estrutura.

O que é e como é realizado o procedimento de análise sintática ascendente e descendente?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De forma [resumida](https://pt.wikibooks.org/wiki/Constru%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_compiladores/An%C3%A1lise_sint%C3%A1tica):

- **Análise sintática ascendente**, também chamada de *bottom-up*, o analisador pode iniciar com um entrada de dados e tentar reescrevê-la até o símbolo inicial. Intuitivamente, o analisador tentar localizar os elementos mais básicos, e então elementos maiores que contêm os elementos mais básicos, e assim por diante. Exemplo: analisador sintático LR (**L**eft-to-right **R**ight-most-derivation).
- **Análise sintática descendente**, também chamada de *top-down*, o analisador pode iniciar com o símbolo inicial e tentar transformá-lo na entrada de dados. Intuitivamente, o analisador inicia dos maiores elementos e os quebra em elementos menores. Exemplo: analisador sintático LL (**L**eft-to-right **L**eft-most-derivation)

---

**Análise sintática**

A análise sintática é a segunda etapa do processo de compilação (a primeira é a [análise léxica](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/An%C3%A1lise_l%C3%A9xica)) e na maioria dos casos utiliza [gramática  livre  de  contexto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/180961/51124) para especificar a sintaxe de uma linguagem de programação. A principal tarefa do analisador sintático, conhecido como *parsing*, é determinar se o programa de entrada representado pelo fluxo de tokens possui as sentenças válidas para a linguagem de programação. No caso afirmativo, queremos adicionalmente  descobrir a maneira (ou uma das maneiras) pela qual a cadeia pode ser  derivada seguindo as regras da gramática.

Fazendo uma analogia gramática da língua portuguesa, que estuda a disposição das palavras em uma frase, essa parte da compilação é responsável por determinar se uma cadeia de símbolos léxicos pode ser gerada por uma gramática.

As gramáticas livres de contexto representam uma gramática formal e pode ser escrita através de algoritmos fazendo a derivação de todas as possíveis construções da linguagem. Essas derivações tem como objetivo determinar se um fluxo de palavras se encaixa na sintaxe da linguagem de programação.

Uma derivação é uma sequência de substituições de não‐terminais por uma escolha das regras de produção gramaticais. Quando fazemos a derivação deve-se aplicar a regra de produção para substituir cada símbolo não terminal por um símbolo terminal, isso permite identificar se certa cadeias de caracteres pertence a linguagem, as regras expandem todas as produções possíveis. Como resultado desse processo temos a árvore de derivação, que é uma alternativa gráfica para mostrar o processo de derivação de uma sentença em uma gramática.

A maneira pela qual a árvore de derivação da cadeia analisada `x` é construída, diz se a análise sintática é descendente ou ascendente.

- **Análise sintática descendente**, também chamada de *top-down*: a árvore de derivação correspondente a `x` é construída de cima para baixo, ou seja, da raiz (o símbolo inicial `S`) para as folhas, onde se encontra `x`. Nesse tipo de análise, é preciso decidir *qual* regra `A→β` será aplicada a um nó rotulado por um não-terminal `A`. A *expansão* de `A` é feita criando nós filhos rotulados com os símbolos de `β`.
- **Análise sintática ascendente**, também chamada de *bottom-up*: a árvore de derivação correspondente a `x` é construída de baixo para cima, ou seja, das folhas, onde se encontra `x`, para a raiz, onde se encontra o símbolo inicial `S`. Nesse tipo de análise, é preciso decidir *quando* a regra `A→β` será aplicada, e devemos encontrar  nós  vizinhos rotulados com os  símbolos de `β`. A *redução* pela regra `A→β` consiste em acrescentar à árvore um nó `A`, cujos filhos são os nós correspondentes aos símbolos de `β`.

Nos dois tipos, as árvores são construídas da esquerda para  a  direita. A razão para isso é que a escolha das regras deve se basear na  cadeia a ser gerada, que é lida da esquerda para a direita.

Exemplo, considere a seguinte gramática e a cadeia `x = a+a*a`:

```
1. E → E + T
2. E → T
3. T → T*F
4. T → F
5. F → (E)
6. F → a
```

Na análise descendente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As regras são consideradas na ordem 1 2 4 6 3 4 6 6, a  mesma  ordem em que as regras são usadas na derivação esquerda:

```
E ⇒ E+T ⇒ T+T⇒ a+T ⇒ a+T*F ⇒ a+F*F ⇒ a+a*F ⇒ a+a*a
```

Com a análise ascendente, por outro lado, as regras são identificadas na ordem 6 4 2 6 4 6 3 1, neste caso, a ordem das regras corresponde à derivação direita, invertida:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
a+a*a ⇐ F+a*a ⇐ T+a*a ⇐ E+a*a ⇐ E+F*a ⇐ E+T*a
```

Ou seja:

```
E ⇒ E+T ⇒ E+T∗F ⇒ E+T∗a ⇒ E+F∗a ⇒ E+a∗a ⇒ T+a∗a ⇒ F+a∗a ⇒ a+a∗a
```

Referências:

- [Análise Sintática](https://johnidm.gitbooks.io/compiladores-para-humanos/content/part1/syntax-analysis.html)
- [Compiladores - Análise Sintática](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~inf1626/Apostila/comp3.pdf)
- [Construção de compiladores/Análise sintática](https://pt.wikibooks.org/wiki/Constru%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_compiladores/An%C3%A1lise_sint%C3%A1tica)