# O que é uma expressão regular?

Tags: regex, terminologia

Em muitos códigos eu vejo funções com um conjunto de caracteres especiais que parecem ter uma função própria.

Vejo isso em praticamente todas as linguagens, então o que ela é afinal, uma classe, uma biblioteca ou o que então ?

Embora exista uma resposta nessa [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/94092/o-que-pode-tornar-uma-express%C3%A3o-regular-lenta), no meu ponto de vista pode estar havendo um confusão de conceitos quando é afirmado:

> regex são Autômato finito determinístico

Ou seja, esta resposta não reponde a esta pergunta no seu conceito básico.

Um autômato finito determinístico é uma máquina de estados finita que por sua vez são reconhecedores de tipos de linguagem formais sendo uma delas expressões regulares e é sobre esta ultima que procuro as definições e características na suas implementações.

Comment: Creio que esta Resposta pode ajudar. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/165413/14213

Comment: Possível duplicata de [O que pode tornar uma expressão regular lenta?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/94092/o-que-pode-tornar-uma-express%c3%a3o-regular-lenta)

Answer (score 19):

É uma *string* que define um padrão de busca. É um algoritmo. Podemos dizer que ela é uma linguagem para localização de padrões em texto.

Ela não é uma [linguagem de programação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102452/101), mas sua implementação está disponível em praticamente todas as bibliotecas padrões das linguagens de programação, ou por biblioteca de terceiros.

Algumas implementações são bem simples tendo apenas uma função, outras possuem diversas classes com diversas utilidades. Algumas linguagens preferiram embuti-la como uma construção. Existem variações de linguagem. Algumas mais mais completas, outras só com os códigos principais.

Podemos dizer que é um [padrão de projeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/96452/101), mas como ela é tão antiga, tão pervasiva, que ninguém nem define desta forma.

É uma forma de obter a localização de padrões de texto dentro de outros textos através de uma sequência de códigos que indiquem como deve ser composto esse padrão para encaixar no que se procura. Outras formas podem ser tediosas, precisarem de códigos maiores e o programador pode errar mais facilmente, ainda que os programadores inexperientes possam criar diversos falsos positivos se não testam adequadamente.

É comum ter funções, que além de localizar faz a mudança de um padrão por algum outro texto.

Normalmente é abreviada como *regex* ou *regexp*.

Particularmente acho ilegível e e prefiro funções que indicam de forma mais "por extenso" o que deseja (algumas linguagens possuem bibliotecas para isso) e ela frequentemente é muito mais lenta que fazer um laço na mão (alguns casos podem ser bem complicado, mas se tiver funções que ajudem não é ruim). Eu respeitaria mais se fosse uma variação de [ABNF](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/178720/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Creio que, o que ele busca é uma explicação mais voltada autômatos finitos e como é interpretado estilo como `[0-9]` se torna uma estado que aceita apenas números.

Comment: Estive procurando no SO sobre expressões regulares para dar como referência em uma outra pergunta e só encontrei esta pergunta/resposta com a definição, a resposta está coerente mas acho que carece de exemplos.

Answer (score 2):

Uma expressão regular é simplesmente um conjunto de caracteres que fazem um padrão de busca, por exemplo, ao invés de escrever o nome completo de um arquivo, você pode escrever o começo do nome seguido do caractere '*', assim vai fazer referência a todos os itens com esse padrão.