# Como pegar trechos entre () de uma string

Tags: c#, string

Estou fazendo um programa que lê uma expressão matemática qualquer como por exemplo `x^(3*x+1) + (cos x)`, não precisa ser necessariamente essa expressão, e gostaria de saber como faço para pegar o trecho especifico entre parenteses da string.
 Sei que com `IndexOf` e `substring` eu consigo pegar o que esta dentro do primeiro parenteses, mas quando tenho mais de 1 não sei o que fazer.

EDIT : O que eu quero fazer é pegar o trecho da string que esta entre os parenteses, no caso `3*x + 1" e "cos x`, mas eu não sei como fazer para pegar o conteúdo do segundo parêntese, `cos x`, pois só sei fazer isso usando `indexof` e substring dessa forma:

```
        string formula = Console.ReadLine();
        string trecho;
        int pos1, pos2;
        pos1 = formula.IndexOf('(');
        pos2 = formula.IndexOf(')');

        trecho = formula.Substring(pos1 + 1 , pos2 - 1);
        Console.WriteLine($"{trecho}");
```

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de pegar o trecho que esta no segundo parênteses também.

Comment: Olá, Renato, bem vindo ao SOpt. O _como_ é um problema de lógica, não necessáriamente de programação... Pode compartilhar conosco que você conseguiu maginar até agora como algorítmo, pelo menos?

Comment: Editei o post com mais algumas informações

Comment: Infelizmente no momento não posso responder á sua pergunta, mas posso comentar. Amigo você pode alcançar o resultado que pretende utilizando [expressões regulares](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/185301/o-que-é-uma-expressão-regular). Aqui vai um [link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DuPvTM) com uma pequena ajuda. Pode utilizar este [site](https://regex101.com) para auxiliar na compreensão da sintaxe das expressões regulares.

Comment: Muito obrigado, vou dar uma estudada nessas expressões regulares, mas era exatamente isso que eu estava procurando

Comment: Sei que sua pergunta se refere à pegar a expressão dentro dos parênteses, mas acredito que você possa resolver esse algoritmo utilizando pilhas ou algumas técnicas já conhecidas

Comment: Fala renato, pega a expressão ai: https://regex101.com/r/KRZNu1/1

Answer (score 1):

Se apenas pretende obter o que está dentro de parêntesis (removendo os próprios parêntesis) pode utilizar a seguinte expressão regular:

```
string formula = Console.ReadLine();
string trecho = Regex.Match(formula, @"(?<=\().+?(?=\))").Value;

Console.WriteLine($"{trecho}");
```

Pode experimentar esta expressão regular em [Regular Expressions 101](https://regex101.com/r/KRZNu1/2).

Answer (score 0):

tente isso:

```
        string formula = Console.ReadLine();
        List<string> trechos = new List<string>();

        int indexParenteses = formula.IndexOf('(');

        while (indexParenteses != -1)
        {
            trechos.Add(formula.Substring(indexParenteses + 1, formula.IndexOf(')', indexParenteses) - indexParenteses - 1));
            indexParenteses = formula.IndexOf('(', indexParenteses + 1);
        }

        trechos.ForEach(p => Console.WriteLine(p));
        Console.Read();
```