# Sorted retorna espaço em branco dentro do Array

Tags: python

Eu quero que o programa receba 2 números e mostre eles em ordem crescente:

```
a = input()
x = a
print(sorted(x))
```

Mas com isso quando eu escrevo `3 2`, ele mostra `[" ", "2", "3"]`.
Como faço pra eliminar o espaço?

Comment: Porque não usa assim: `print(sorted([int(x) for x in input() if x.isdigit()]))` ?

Comment: @gato O problema é se tiver números com mais de um dígito (como  `12 3`, por exemplo): https://ideone.com/ihagh3

Comment: @hkotsubo celular eh ruim de digitar, falto o `split()` :)

Answer (score 5):

Primeiro entenda que [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) retorna uma string. Então se você digita `3 2`, isso é uma string (um texto). Embora tenha dois números nesta string, eles não são interpretados como números de fato.

E quando você passa uma string para [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted), o resultado é uma lista na qual cada elemento é um caractere da string:

```
print(sorted('bdca')) # ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

No exemplo acima, o resultado é a lista `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`. Se a string tiver espaços, eles também são considerados na ordenação. Outro detalhe é que se tiver números com mais de um dígito, cada dígito também é considerado um caractere:

```
print(sorted('12 3')) # [' ', '1', '2', '3']
```

No caso acima, a saída é `[' ', '1', '2', '3']` - os caracteres da string ordenados segundo a ordem "alfabética" (na verdade, segundo a [ordem definida pelos seus Code Points do Unicode](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types)).

---

Então para obter os números, primeiro você deve separá-los por espaço. Para isso você pode usar [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), que vai criar uma lista com os elementos separados por espaço. Assim, a string `'3 2'` vira a lista `['3', '2']`.

Em seguida podemos usar [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) para converter cada elemento desta lista para número, e usar `sorted` para ordernar os números em ordem crescente.

Por fim, também pode usar [`isdigit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) para se certificar que o elemento é de fato um número:

```
a = '12 3 2 5343'
x = sorted(int(n) for n in a.split(' ') if n.isdigit())
print(x)
```

Isso imprime:

> [2, 3, 12, 5343]

*Coloquei um valor fixo na variável `a` para exemplificar, mas você pode usar `input()` sem problemas.*

---

#### "Soluções" erradas

**Atenção**, se você não usar `split`, cada dígito será considerado individualmente:

```
a = '12 3 2 5343'
# código sem split, cada dígito é considerado um elemento separado da lista
x = sorted(int(n) for n in a if n.isdigit())
print(x)
```

Isso imprime:

> [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5]

Isso acontece porque ao iterar uma string, a cada iteração o valor de `n` [será um único caractere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/538352). Para não ocorrer esse problema e considerar números com mais de um dígito corretamente, use `split` como já indicado.

E se usar `split` mas não usar `int` para converter para números, os valores serão todos strings, então eles serão ordenados segundo a ordem lexicográfica ("alfabética"):

```
a = '12 3 2 5343'
# código com split, mas não usa int() para transformar os elementos em número
x = sorted(n for n in a.split(' ') if n.isdigit())
print(x) # ['12', '2', '3', '5343']
```

O resultado é `['12', '2', '3', '5343']`. Repare que os números são mostrados entre aspas, indicando que na verdade são strings (já que eu não usei `int()` para transformá-los em números). Por isso eles são ordenados segundo a ordem "alfabética" (que considera os [code points do Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode#Architecture_and_terminology)).

Somente transformando as strings em números você garante que a ordem correta será usada.

O problema dessas "soluções" erradas é que elas "funcionam" para casos simples, como `3 2` (ou qualquer outra string que só tenha números com um dígito). Mas se tiver algum número com mais de um dígito, já não funcionam mais.

---

#### `split` com vários espaços

Se os elementos tiverem mais de um espaço separando-os, basta usar o [módulo `re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), que possui um método `split`, só que "turbinado" (já que aceita qualquer [expressão regular](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/185301/112052) como parâmetro):

```
import re

a = '12    3    2   5343'
x = sorted(int(n) for n in re.split(r'\s+', a) if n.isdigit())
print(x)
```

No caso, usei o [atalho `\s`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-30), que corresponde a espaço, <kbd>TAB</kbd>, quebra de linha e outros (veja a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-30) para mais detalhes). E usando o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`, eu indico que quero separar por um ou mais espaços. O resultado é:

> [2, 3, 12, 5343]

---

#### Números negativos

Um detalhe é que `isdigit()` retorna `False` para números negativos:

```
print('-1'.isdigit()) # False
```

Caso queira tratar números negativos, uma alternativa é fazer uma função que tentar converter os elementos da lista para número (usando `int`), e caso não consiga, ignora:

```
def converte(lista):
    for elemento in lista:
        try:
            # tenta converter para número
            yield int(elemento)
        except ValueError:
            pass # não é número, ignora

a = '12    3    -2   5343 aasdfasd'
x = sorted(n for n in converte(re.split(r'\s+', a)))
print(x)
```

Nesse caso não preciso mais usar `isdigit()`, pois a verificação é feita dentro da função `converte`. Quando o elemento não for um número, a função `int()` lança um `ValueError`, e simplesmente ignoro o elemento (como foi o caso do elemento `aasdfasd`). O resultado é:

> [-2, 3, 12, 5343]

Answer (score -1):

Amigo, tem uma solução muito mais facil!

```
a = input()
x = a.replace(' ', '') # <- Remove os espaços!
print(sorted(x))
```

Dai vc tbm pode transforma em int novamente:

```
x = int(x)
```

Comment: Não funcionará, pois não considera números com mais de um dígito. Se eu entrar com "12 10 11" eu esperaria a resposta "10, 11, 12", mas sua solução traria "0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2", o que não faria sentido.

Comment: Além do que o Anderson disse, se a entrada for a string `3 2` (ou seja, os números 3 e 2), a última linha do código resulta no número 32, que não faz sentido: https://ideone.com/5xlzNt