# Subtrair 4 horários e exibir ao mesmo tempo o resultado em outro input

Tags: javascript, data, time

Estou com essa dúvida de como vou pegar esses 4 campos (Horário início, fim e intervalo início e fim) e subtrair eles e aparecer a resposta em outro `input` no carga horária semanal.

O código é esse (preciso de uma função em JavaScript):

```
<div id="divHorarios" style="display: none">
    <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-4">
        <label for="horarioInicio"><br>Horário de início: <font color="red">*</font>
        </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtHorarioInicio"
            placeholder="Exemplo: 08:00" style="height: 43px;"/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-4">
        <label for="intervaloInicio"><br>Início do intervalo: <font color="red">*
            </font>
        </label>
        <input type="text" maxlength="5" class="form-control" id="txtIntervaloInicio"
            placeholder="Exemplo: 12:00" style="height: 43px;"/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-4">
        <label for="intervaloFim"><br>Fim do intervalo: <font color="red">*</font>
        </label>
        <input type="text" maxlength="5" class="form-control" id="txtIntervaloFim"
            placeholder="Exemplo: 13:00" style="height: 43px;"/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-4">
        <label for="horarioFim"><br>Horario de Término: <font color="red">*</font>
        </label>
        <input type="text" maxlength="5" class="form-control" id="txtHorarioFim"
            placeholder="Exemplo: 18:00" style="height: 43px;"/>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="carga-horaria"><br>Carga Horária Semanal: <font color="blue">*
            </font>
        </label>
        <input type="text" style="width:150px" class="form-control" id="carga-horaria"
            placeholder="" style="height: 43px;" readonly>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="carga-horaria">Carga Horária Total: <font color="blue">*</font>
        </label>
        <input type="text" style="width:150px" class="form-control" id="carga-horaria-total"
            placeholder="" style="height: 43px;" readonly>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro, você poderia utilizar o [`input type="time"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time) em vez de `type="text"`. Caso o [browser seja compatível](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time#Browser_compatibility) e suporte este tipo, ele já limita o formato de entrada para `hh:mm` (caso o browser não suporte, na parte final da resposta há uma alternativa).

Infelizmente o JavaScript [não provê uma maneira de trabalhar **apenas** com horários](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17901480), já que a classe [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) representa na verdade um [timestamp](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70473/112052) (um instante específico na linha do tempo, e portanto pode representar uma data e hora diferente em cada fuso horário).

Uma alternativa é fazer o *parsing* manualmente, e calcular a diferença em minutos entre os horários. O [valor de um campo `input type="time"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time#Time_value_format) é o horário no formato `hh:mm`, sendo que o campo das horas varia entre 0 e 23. Sendo assim, uma maneira de separar a hora dos minutos é usando [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) para quebrar a string em duas partes, e [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) para converter estas strings em números. Exemplo:

```js
let [hora, minuto] = '10:00'.split(':').map(v => parseInt(v));
```

A linha acima funciona se o browser já suporta [*Destructuring Assignment*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Browser_compatibility) e [*Arrow Functions*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Browser_compatibility). Caso o browser não suporte esta sintaxe, você pode fazer:

```js
let partes = '10:00'.split(':');
let hora = parseInt(partes[0]);
let minuto = parseInt(partes[1]);
```

Em seguida, basta calcular a diferença em minutos entre esses horários e no final converter esta diferença em minutos para o equivalente em horas e minutos. O código segue abaixo (dei uma "limpada" no seu HTML, retirando os `div`'s e as classes CSS, apenas para focar no mecanismo em si):

```js
function ajustaHorario(idCampo) {
    let valorCampo = document.getElementById(idCampo).value;
    let [hora, minuto] = valorCampo.split(':').map(v => parseInt(v));
    return (hora * 60) + minuto;
}

function calculaTotal() {
    // diferença entre horário de início e o início do intervalo
    let totalAntesIntervalo = ajustaHorario('intervaloInicio') - ajustaHorario('horarioInicio');
    // diferença entre fim do intervalo e o horário de término
    let totalDepoisIntervalo = ajustaHorario('horarioFim') - ajustaHorario('intervaloFim');
    
    // tempo total (em minutos)
    let total = totalAntesIntervalo + totalDepoisIntervalo;
    
    // quebrar o total em horas e minutos
    let totalHoras = Math.floor(total / 60);
    let totalMinutos = total % 60;
    
    // colocar o valor no campo
    document.getElementById('cargaHorariaTotal').value = totalHoras + ' horas e ' + totalMinutos + ' minutos';
}
```

```html
<label for="horarioInicio"><br>Horário de início:</label>
<input type="time" id="horarioInicio" placeholder="Exemplo: 08:00" />

<label for="intervaloInicio"><br>Início do intervalo:</label>
<input type="time" maxlength="5" id="intervaloInicio" placeholder="Exemplo: 12:00" />

<label for="intervaloFim"><br>Fim do intervalo:</label>
<input type="time" maxlength="5" id="intervaloFim" placeholder="Exemplo: 13:00" />

<label for="horarioFim"><br>Horario de Término:</label>
<input type="time" maxlength="5" id="horarioFim" placeholder="Exemplo: 18:00" />

<br><label for="carga-horaria">Carga Horária Total:</label>
<input type="text" id="cargaHorariaTotal" readonly>

<br><input type="button" value="Calcular Total" onclick="calculaTotal()">
```

---

O formato da carga horário total está em texto ("X horas e Y minutos"), mas você também pode colocar em outros formatos, como `hh:mm`. Só lembrando que esse formato serve para **horas do dia**, mas o que o valor total representa é na verdade uma **duração**. Essas são duas coisas que você não deve confundir:

- um horário representa um **ponto específico** do dia. Ex: o intervalo começou às 11:30 (11 horas e 30 minutos, da manhã)
- uma duração representa uma quantidade de tempo. Ex: hoje eu trabalhei 8 horas e 20 minutos (eu não disse que horas comecei ou terminei, se teve intervalo, nada disso, é apenas a **quantidade** de tempo, não necessariamente relacionada a um horário específico)

Apesar de ambos usarem as mesmas palavras (horas, minutos, etc), eles não são a mesma coisa. Os campos `input type="time"` representam horários, e o total que foi calculado representa uma duração.

Você até pode escrever uma duração de 8 horas e 20 minutos como `"08:20"`, mas não deve confundir isso com o horário "8 e 20 da manhã". Eu optei por escrever a duração como texto, mas se quiser, você pode formatá-la como `hh:mm`:

```js
document.getElementById('cargaHorariaTotal').value =
    totalHoras.toString().padStart(2, '0')
    + ':' + totalMinutos.toString().padStart(2, '0');
```

---

Este código é bem "ingênuo", pois não verifica se o horário de saída é maior que a entrada, por exemplo. Você pode fazer esta verificação comparando os valores de `ajustaHorario(campo)`. Além disso, o código só lida com horários, então assume-se que todos os horários pertencem ao mesmo dia.

---

### Caso o browser não suporte o `input type="time"`

Quando o browser não suporta o `input type="time"`, este se comporta como um campo de texto comum. Mas você pode limitar os valores aceitos usando um [`pattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-pattern), conforme [sugerido na documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time#Handling_browser_support).

No exemplo abaixo eu coloquei o campo como `text` apenas para você ver como funcionaria caso o campo fosse `time` e o browser não tivesse suporte ao mesmo. Mas no seu código eu deixaria sempre como `time`:

```html
<form>
<input type="text" id="horarioInicio" placeholder="Exemplo: 08:00" required
 pattern="([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9])"/>

<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Dessa forma, o campo só aceita valores no formato `hh:mm`, com o valor das horas entre 00 e 23 e dos minutos entre 00 e 59.

O `pattern` contém uma [expressão regular](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/185301/112052) (também chamada de regex), indicando o formato aceito no campo.

Os colchetes formam uma [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). Por exemplo, `[01]` significa "o dígito zero ou o dígito 1", enquanto `[0-9]` é "qualquer dígito de 0 a 9".

O `|` significa [alternância](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html), então `[01][0-9]|2[0-3]` significa:

- o dígito 0 ou 1, seguido de um dígito de 0 a 9, **ou**
- o dígito 2, seguido de um dígito de 0 a 3

Com isso, garanto que as horas podem ser de 00 a 23.

Em seguida temos `:`, e por fim `[0-5][0-9]` (um dígito de 0 a 5, seguido de um dígito de 0 a 9), garantindo que os minutos podem ser de 00 a 59.