# substituir mais de um char utitlizando .replace()

Tags: java, string, replace

Tenho a seguinte função:

```
public String replaceCharToNull(int row, int colum)
{
    String result;
    
    result = (((String)jTableLoan.getModel().getValueAt(row, colum)).replace("x", ""));
    return result;
}
```

Preciso remover dois caracteres "x" e "%", tem uma forma de fazer tipo um: `.replace("x" || "%", ""));`

Ou

Preciso criar outra função para substituir o `%` ao invés de fazer isso na mesma função?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depende do que você precisa.

> *Preciso remover dois caracteres "x" e "%"*

Isso quer dizer que você quer remover o `x` e o `%` independente de onde eles estiverem, ou somente se um estiver depois do outro (somente se for `x%`)?

---

### Remover somente `x%`

Se for para remover somente `x%`, você pode usar o próprio `replace`:

```
System.out.println("abcx%123 blax%etc".replace("x%", "")); // abc123 blaetc
```

Claro que usar `replaceAll`, como sugeriu a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/472963/112052), também funciona. Ela cita que `replaceAll` aceita regex, o que é verdade, mas neste caso específico não faz diferença, porque ao usar um texto fixo como `"x%"`, não precisa de uma expressão regular propriamente dita (ou seja, foi mencionada uma vantagem que no fim não foi usada, pois é indiferente usar um ou outro para este caso - se quiser saber mais sobre regex, veja [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/185301/112052)).

Na verdade `replace` para textos fixos é melhor, porque `replaceAll` trata qualquer string como uma expressão regular, o que quer dizer que internamente será criada uma instância de [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), que não é um dos objetos mais "leves" e "baratos" que existem. A grosso modo, se não precisa de regex, não use. Se for para substituir um texto fixo, prefira usar `replace` (claro que para programas pequenos a diferença será insignificante, mas em aplicações maiores, talvez valha a pena levar isso em consideração).

E como já dito, neste caso só será removido `x%`. Se tiver um `x` ou um `%` separados, eles não serão substituídos:

```
System.out.println("abcx%123xbl%ax%etc".replace("x%", ""));    // abc123xbl%aetc
System.out.println("abcx%123xbl%ax%etc".replaceAll("x%", "")); // abc123xbl%aetc
```

Repare que ele só removeu o `x%`, mas o `x` antes do `b` e o `%` antes do último `a` permaneceram.

---

### Remover `x` ou `%`

Se a ideia é remover o `x` ou `%` independente deles estarem juntos ou não, aí a abordagem é diferente.

Uma opção é usar 2 chamadas de `replace`:

```
System.out.println("abcx%123xbl%ax%etc".replace("x", "").replace("%", "")); // abc123blaetc
```

A primeira remove todos os `x` e a segunda remove todos os `%`.

Outra opção é usar `replaceAll`, e neste caso sim é "justificado" o uso de regex:

```
System.out.println("abcx%123xbl%ax%etc".replaceAll("[x%]", "")); // abc123blaetc
```

A expressão `[x%]` é uma [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), que significa "o caractere `x` ou o caractere `%`" (qualquer um deles). Sendo assim, qualquer um deles será substituído por `""` (o que é o mesmo que removê-los). É importante notar que se eu retirar os colchetes, o `x%` passa a ser tratado como um texto fixo e só remove o `x%`, mas não o `x` e `%` separadamente.

---

Um dos problemas de chamar `replace` várias vezes é que cada chamada cria uma nova `String` (em Java, strings são imutáveis e todo método que "modifica" algo na verdade retorna outra string).

Claro que para apenas dois caracteres e poucas strings pequenas sendo executado poucas vezes não fará muita diferença, mas se a lista de caracteres fosse maior, eu teria que chamar `replace` várias vezes, criando várias strings intermediárias. E usar uma regex (com `replaceAll`, mesmo que seja apenas uma vez) também tem lá o seu *overhead*.

Talvez seja micro-otimização (ou talvez fique pior, ou não faça diferença, só testando para saber), mas uma terceira alternativa é fazer a substituição manualmente, seja usando um `StringBuilder`:

```
String original = "abcx%123xbl%ax%etc";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < original.length(); i++) {
    char c = original.charAt(i);
    if (c != 'x' && c != '%') {
        sb.append(c); // só adiciono na nova string se não for "x" nem "%"
    }
}
String nova = sb.toString();
```

Ou construindo um array de `char`:

```
String original = "abcx%123xbl%ax%etc";
char[] chars = new char[original.length()];
int tamanhoNovo = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < original.length(); i++) {
    char c = original.charAt(i);
    if (c != 'x' && c != '%') {
        chars[tamanhoNovo] = c;
        tamanhoNovo++;
    }
}
String nova = new String(chars, 0, tamanhoNovo);
```

Comment: No meu caso,  foi mais fácil de resolver utilizando  o  `System.out.println("abcx%123xbl%ax%etc".replace("x", "").replace("%", ""));` , visto que minha função pode receber Strings com o `x` ou com `%`, não recebe os dois de vez, mas sim receber um ou o outro.  Antes de continuar o código vou dar uma lida nos links que vc deixou para entender mais a fundo como funciona...Como esse código lida com muitas convenções, pode ser que eu tenha problemas lá  frente. Obrigado mais uma vez, @hkotsubo

Answer (score 1):

Use o `replaceAll`, ele aceita regex. Por exemplo:

```
"abcx%123".replaceAll("x%", "")
```

O resultado será "abc123".

Comment: Muito obrigado ! Mas nessa situação o que seria regex ?

Comment: Regex (Regular Expression) é um mecanismo para busca e substituição de caracteres numa string. É um tema bem amplo e pode ser utilizado para testes mais complexos como (por exemplo) determinar se uma string representa um email válido, ou remover todos caracteres não numéricos.