# O que significa o parâmetro / +/g no método .split()?

Tags: javascript, string, regex, split

Alguém consegue me explicar o que significa o parâmetro `/ +/g` dentro de um método `.split()`?

```js
var message = "-lucas o p i ";
var args = message.slice(1).trim().split(/ +/g);
var comando = args.shift().toLowerCase();
console.log('Entrada:', message);
console.log('Argumentos:', args);
console.log('Comando:', comando);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Isso é uma [expressão regular](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/185301/112052) (regex). As barras são os delimitadores (elas não fazem parte da expressão propriamente dita, só servem para indicar que dentro dela tem uma regex).

A expressão em si é um espaço seguido do [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`, que significa "uma ou mais ocorrências". Sendo assim, a regex significa "um ou mais espaços".

Já o `g` no final é uma das [muitas *flags*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_searching_with_flags) que modificam o comportamento da mesma. No caso, o `g` habilita a busca global, mas ao contrário do que afirmava a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/477825/112052) (antes de ser [editada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/477825/revisions)), ela **não tem nada a ver com quebras de linha** (mais abaixo explico em mais detalhes).

---

No caso do [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), a regex serve para indicar qual o separador que será usado para quebrar a string em várias partes. Então neste caso ela separa a string por espaços (ela procura por um ou mais espaços, e quebra a string em várias partes, retornando um array com essas partes).

Um detalhe importante é que no caso do `split` a *flag* `g` não faz a menor diferença, veja:

```js
let s = 'ab cd    efg   hi';

// sem a flag g
console.log(s.split(/ +/)); // [ 'ab', 'cd', 'efg', 'hi' ]

// com a flag g (o resultado é o mesmo)
console.log(s.split(/ +/g)); // [ 'ab', 'cd', 'efg', 'hi' ]
```

Veja que no `split` não faz diferença usar a *flag* `g`. O `split` sempre usará a regex para quebrar a string.

---

**Então quando usar o `g` faz diferença?**

A *flag* `g` faz diferença no [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). Por exemplo, se eu quiser substituir os espaços por uma vírgula:

```js
let s = 'ab cd    efg   hi';

// sem flag g, substitui apenas a primeira ocorrência
console.log(s.replace(/ +/, ',')); // ab,cd    efg   hi

// com flag g, substitui todas as ocorrências
console.log(s.replace(/ +/g, ',')); // ab,cd,efg,hi
```

Sem a *flag* `g`, apenas a primeira ocorrência de espaços é substituída pela vírgula. Com a *flag*, todas as ocorrências são substituídas.

Outro caso em que faz diferença é para buscar as ocorrências da regex na string. Ex:

```js
let s = 'ab1cd2ef3gh4';

// sem flag g, retorna a primeira ocorrência e mais algumas informações relacionadas
console.log(s.match(/\d/)); // [ '1', index: 2, input: 'ab1cd2ef3gh4', groups: undefined ]
// com flag g, retorna todas as ocorrências
console.log(s.match(/\d/g)); // [ '1', '2', '3', '4' ]
```

No exemplo acima usei a expressão `\d` (um [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) para "dígito de 0 a 9"). Sem a *flag* `g` é retornada apenas a primeira ocorrência do dígito (no caso, o `1`), além de algumas informações relacionadas (como a posição em que foi encontrado, etc). Já com a *flag* `g` foram retornadas todas as ocorrências de dígitos da string (obs: no *snippet* do site o primeiro caso retorna apenas `[ 1 ]`, mas rodando no console do browser e no Node, é retornado o array indicado acima, com todas as informações já mencionadas).

E como você pode notar, não há nenhuma quebra de linha na string, pois o fato de ter ou não quebras de linha não tem relação nenhuma com a *flag* `g`. O que muda é o comportamento da regex em determinadas situações (para buscar *matches* faz diferença, para um `split` não), independente do conteúdo da string (tanto faz se tem quebras de linha ou não).

Segue um exemplo de string com quebras de linha, e veja que o comportamento não muda: sem a *flag* `g`, ele só retorna a primeira ocorrência, e com a *flag*, retorna todas as ocorrências:

```js
// string com quebras de linha (o '\n')
let s = 'ab\n\nxyz 1cd2ef3gh4';

// sem flag g, retorna a primeira ocorrência e mais algumas informações relacionadas
console.log(s.match(/\d/)); // [ '1', index: 8, input: 'ab\n\nxyz 1cd2ef3gh4', groups: undefined ]
// com flag g, retorna todas as ocorrências
console.log(s.match(/\d/g)); // [ '1', '2', '3', '4' ]
```

Repare que o primeiro dígito encontrado (`1`) está na terceira linha, e mesmo sem a *flag* `g` ele foi encontrado. Por isso a afirmação da outra resposta ("*Por padrão, buscaria apenas na primeira linha*") estava errada (após a [edição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/477825/revisions) esta informação foi corrigida). A única coisa que a *flag* `g` faz é mudar o comportamento de buscar apenas a primeira ocorrência (ele passa a buscar todas as ocorrências), e não tem relação nenhuma com quebras de linha.

---

No caso específico do seu código, ele pega a string `"-lucas o p i "` e faz o `slice(1)` para ignorar o primeiro caractere, resultando na string `"lucas o p i "`.
Depois `trim()` elimina os espaços do início e fim, resultando em `"lucas o p i"`.
Em seguida o `split` faz a quebra por espaços, resultando no array `[ 'lucas', 'o', 'p', 'i' ]`.
Por fim, `shift` remove o primeiro elemento deste array ("lucas") e joga na variável `comando`. E no array sobram os outros elementos, ficando `[ 'o', 'p', 'i' ]`.

---

**Obs**: não relacionado à pergunta, mas só pra constar, existe também a *flag* `m` (multiline), e esta sim tem relação com quebras de linha. No caso, esta *flag* modifica o comportamento dos [marcadores `^` e `$`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html): sem a *flag* `m`, eles correspondem respectivamente ao início e fim da string, e com a *flag*, eles passam a considerar também o início e fim de uma linha. Ex:

```js
// "abc", quebra de linha, "123"
let s = 'abc\n123';

// sem flag m, procura por "c" no final da string
console.log(s.match(/c$/)); // null, não encontra nada

// com flag m, procura por "c" no final da string ou no final de uma linha
console.log(s.match(/c$/m)); // [ 'c', index: 2, input: 'abc\n123', groups: undefined ]
```

Answer (score 6):

É uma Regex ou Expressão Regular. Basicamente, está especificando que a string será dividida a cada espaço branco encontrado.

Explicando melhor

O `//` é o inicio e fim da expressão.

O espaço entre `/ /` irá buscar por literalmente espaços em branco na string.

O `+` é um operador de repetição e no seu caso, determina que busque por todos os espaços em branco 1 ou mais vezes.

O `g` é uma flag de global, ou seja, irá buscar a expressão entre `//` em toda a sua string. Por padrão, buscaria apenas a primeira ocorrência.

Da uma conferida no teste feito com a string `-lucas o p i` que você mencionou:
https://regex101.com/r/s6N9zA/1/