# Como criar uma regex equivalente a uma BNF?

Tags: python, regex

Preciso criar uma expressão regular que seja equivalente à seguinte BNF:

```
<SEQ> ::= <DIG><SEQ> | <DIG>
<DIG> ::= 0|1
```

Tentei criar um código em Python com a biblioteca regex:

```
import re

reg = r'[0-2]'

print(reg)
```

Era um teste, mas não consegui criar de fato uma regex que seja equivalente à BNF.

Comment: E você tá usando qual string pra tentar procurar por ocorrências usando a expressão regular em questão?

Comment: A regex teria que ser `[0-2]`, mas dependendo do que vc precisa pode não ser o suficiente. Sem contar que você só criou uma string mas não está usando regex de fato. Se puder [edit] a pergunta e colocar mais detalhes (por exemplo, de qual texto vc quer extrair os números, etc)

Comment: Não cheguei a incluir string, na verdade estou com muita dúvida nesse tema em questão. Se puder me ajudar.

Comment: "*mas não consegui fazer exibir a sequência numérica*", que sequência?

Comment: Já alterei a questão, seria uma sequência de 0 a 2.

Comment: Ainda está confuso. Capturar uma sequência de números é uma coisa (dá a entender que vc vai extrair isso de algum outro lugar). Exibir a sequência é outra coisa. O que exatamente o programa deveria fazer?

Comment: Alterei a pergunta, preciso criar um programa que exiba uma sequência numérica de acordo com a BNF:

<SEQ> ::= <DIG><SEQ> | <DIG>
<DIG> ::= 0|1

Comment: Para conhecer o verdadeiro funcionamento das expressões regulares [Leia isto](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3.8/howto/regex.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se a ideia é gerar uma regex equivalente a esta BNF, então seria algo assim:

```
import re

r = re.compile('^[01]+$')

print(r.match('010100111')) # retorna um objeto Match
print(r.match('010120111')) # None
```

A regex usa os [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$` que indicam respectivamente o início e fim da string.

Depois temos a [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[01]` que significa "um dígito `0` ou `1`" e o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+` que indica uma ou mais ocorrências. Assim, a regex reconhece uma sequência de zeros e uns, de tamanho mínimo 1 e sem limite máximo (exatamente o mesmo que a BNF representa).

No exemplo acima, podemos ver que se a string só tem zeros e uns, é encontrado um *match*, e se tiver qualquer caractere diferente, não encontra nada.

Obs: eu até poderia usar `[0-1]` em vez de `[01]`, mas neste caso dá na mesma ("um digito de 0 a 1" e "o dígito 0 ou 1" é basicamente a mesma coisa).

---

> Antes da [edição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/478225/revisions) e dos comentários, não estava claro que o objetivo era gerar a regex acima. De qualquer forma, vou manter a versão que tentava responder à [pergunta original](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/a154a6c9-342a-4d63-94ee-c28cf54212f8/view-source).

Se dada uma BNF, você quer criar uma sequência que corresponda à definição, então [regex](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/185301/112052) **não** é a ferramenta certa para a tarefa.

No caso, você teria que implementar na mão, ou usar alguma lib pronta. Uma alternativa é usar o [NLTK](https://www.nltk.org/). Como eu não uso muito esse tipo de coisa, acabei pegando um exemplo [daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50036589) e adaptando para o seu caso:

```
from nltk import CFG
from nltk.parse.generate import generate

# cria a gramática a partir da BNF
grammar = CFG.fromstring(""" SEQ -> DIG SEQ | DIG
    DIG -> "0" | "1" """)

# gera várias "palavras" válidas da gramática
for production in generate(grammar, depth=5):
    print(' '.join(production))
```

No caso acima, a saída foi:

```
0 0 0
0 0 1
0 1 0
0 1 1
0 0
0 1
1 0 0
1 0 1
1 1 0
1 1 1
1 0
1 1
0
1
```

A partir daí você pode ler a documentação ([aqui](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.html?highlight=grammar#module-nltk.grammar) e [aqui](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.parse.html?highlight=nltk%20parse#module-nltk.parse.generate)) para gerar exatamente o que você precisa.

Pois a gramática em questão gera uma sequência *potencialmente infinita* de zeros e uns (e não "uma sequência de 0 a 2", como originalmente dito), então não está claro se você precisa gerar alguma sequência qualquer que seja válida, ou alguma específica, ou todas de determinado tamanho, etc.

Mas a ideia geral provavelmente é essa...

Comment: Muito obrigada, pela ajuda.
Eu precisaria no caso criar uma sequência com a biblioteca regex de forma que representasse a BNF que mostrei acima, não exatamente resolvesse ela, entendeu?
Mas já me ajudou bastante.

Comment: @CamillaMarques Atualizei a resposta

Comment: Muito obrigada! Agora consegui entender melhor.

Comment: Achei essa playlist aqui no youtube tbm, muito boa: 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wBI0yv2FG6U&list=PLbIBj8vQhvm1VnTa2Np5vDzCxVtyaYLMr&index=1

Comment: tenho outra dúvida com relação a esse mesmo tema, precisava de ajuda para criar uma regex equivalente a essas duas BNF's:

<list> ::= <element><list> | <element>
<element> ::= <letter><digit>
<letter> ::= A | B 
<digit> ::= 1|2

________________________________________________________________________

<exp> ::= <exp> + <exp> | <term>
<term> ::= <term> * <term> | <factor>
<factor> ::= ( <exp> ) | <digit>
<digit> ::= 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9

Comment: @CamillaMarques Então é o caso de [abrir outra pergunta](/questions/ask). A ideia do site é ter uma pergunta por problema específico - e além disso, uma nova pergunta fica visível na página principal para todos verem (aqui nos comentários menos gente vai ver, provavelmente só eu, o que diminui as chances de ter uma resposta) e assim o site também fica mais organizado :-)

Comment: Feito : https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/482315/como-usar-regex-para-representar-uma-bnf-mais-complexa