# Dúvidas sobre a biblioteca padrão C

Tags: c, biblioteca, extern

Eu notei que os arquivo de cabeçalho (`.h`) são diferentes, em diferentes compiladores. Então eu tenho a duvida, será que este "padrão C ANSI" apenas definiu quais funções devem ter a biblioteca padrão e não às escreveu. Ou se esses compiladores **não são padrão**, e por isso eles mesmos definiram esses arquivos (`.h`).

Analisando os arquivos de cabeçalho eu percebi a ausência do comando **extern**, e eu não entendo o porque disso, afinal essas funções (`printf()`, `puts()`, etc.) estão definidas em arquivos binários, ou seja, deveria ter algo escrito como `extern int printf(const char*, ...)`, ou parecido. Por que o comando `extern` fica ausente?

Comment: A questão do `extern` parece ser uma outra pergunta diferente e que precisaria mostrar melhor sobre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu parei para pensar sobre a ausência `extern` e cheguei numa conclusão. Isso tem a ver com o conceito de **modularização**.
Sabe quando você cria um arquivo (.h) e outro (.c) e ambos tem o mesmo nome, o que ta no arquivo (.c) é acessível pelo (.h), mesmo sem usar o **extern**. E o mesmo acontece por exemplo com um arquivo ***my_file.h*** e ***my_file.lib***.

Answer (score 3):

O padrão define a [especificação, cada um faz como quiser a implementação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111284/101). Desde que a implementação cumpra tudo o que está na especificação ela pode fazer como quiser e estará de acordo com o padrão. Pode inclusive fazer muito mais. Claro que corre o risco de um dia aquilo ser especificado de uma outra forma e ele terá que abandonar o que criou em favor do que foi especificado para se conformar com o padrão.

Em geral os compiladores querem estar dentro do padrão, mas existem alguns menos conhecidos que não estão. Praticamente é considerado um compilador de uma outra linguagem parecida com C, mas não é C mesmo.

Comment: E sobre o `extern`, tem alguma explicação ou recomendação de algum site que explique?

Comment: @Filipe_Br Não, mas se fizer outra pergunta sobre isso, eu posso tentar ver, ou quem sabe outra pessoa possa responder. Mas coloque onde viu de um jeito, que jeito você acha que deveria ser, e porque acha assim. Aí uma boa resposta pode surgir.