# Qual a diferença entre C e C99?

Tags: c, característica-linguagem

Vi C99 em texto e fiquei curioso existe alguma diferença entre o C normal e o C99?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 14):

C é a linguagem. Em 84 ela começou se tornar ANSI após um comitê liberar primeiros rascunhos da especificação da linguagem.

Em 89 ela teve sua [especificação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111284/101) ratificada mundialmente e algumas pessoas chamam de C89. Em 99 houve uma atualização dessa especificação chamada C99 e teve outra em 2011 chamada C11, finalmente [chegamos na C18](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/328085/101), que é quase irrelevante.

Os compiladores deveriam se conformar com uma das especificações e dizer isso.

Um [rascunho](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) dela.

Obviamente que cada revisão coloca novos recursos (bom, C11 deixou alguns antes obrigatórios como opcionais, e tornou obsoleto alguns outros).

Alguns exemplos de novidades adicionadas nela:

- Funções em linha
- Remoção de restrições sobre a localização da declaração de variáveis (como em C++)
- Adição de vários tipos de dados novos, incluindo o `long long int` (para minimizar problemas na transição de 32-bits para 64-bits), um tipo de dados `boolean` explicito (chamado `_Bool`) e um tipo `complex` que representa números complexos
- Vetores de dados de comprimento variável (o vetor pode ter um tamanho diferente a cada execução de uma função, mas não cresce depois de criado)
- Suporte oficial para comentários de uma linha iniciados por `//`, emprestados da linguagem C++
- Várias funções de biblioteca novas, tais como `snprintf()`
- Vários arquivos cabeçalho novos, tais como `stdint.h`

[Mais](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).