# Qual é a versão mais atualizada da linguagem C e qual é o compilador que melhor funciona?

Tags: c

Qual é a versão mais atualizada da linguagem C e qual é o compilador que melhor funciona?

Comment: A versão mais atualizada da linguagem (não de compiladores específicos) é de dezembro de 2011. Dizer qual é o compilador que melhor funciona depende muito de opinião pessoal, ainda mais sem você descrever as situações ou cenários que você considera pertinentes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hoje C18 é a especificação mais atualizada onde GCC 8 e Clang 6 estão suportando, mas em essência muda nada importante em relação ao C11.

Poucas pessoas usam o C11, a especificação anterior e que importa agora, porque recursos dela não são suportados pela maioria dos compiladores e seria problemático portar. Até adotam alguma coisa porque parte dela é dizer que algumas coisas do C99 não são mais obrigatórias.

Em geral adota-se C99, alguns preferem C89 que é muito atrasada (a primeira especificação universal) e na prática só é necessária se for usar em compiladores muito ruins ou obscuros, e se precisar suportá-lo no seu código, já terá que fazer outras coisas específicas. [Raro o compilador que suporta 100% do C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99#Implementations), mas o que não é suportado já é polêmico e evita-se usar por outros motivos.

Então na prática o que adota-se é um híbrido de C89, C99 e C11.

Não existe isso de compilador que melhor funciona. Ou funciona ou não. Alguns podem fazer algo melhor, mas é ponto específico e não geral.

Quem usa no Windows tende usar o compilador da Microsoft. Já em Linux tendem usar o GCC, no Mac usam Clang, mas este tem sido adotado por muita gente, inclusive meio que virou padrão em no FreeBSD. Há alguns que usam Intel por otimizações específicas, mas é raro. Outros só são usados por causa de plataforma ou necessidade específica ou legado. Os primeiros suportam todas as principais plataformas. Sim, ao contrário do que você pensa, o compilador da Microsoft gera código perfeito para Linux, Mac, Android, etc.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Pode-se dizer que a versão mais usada é a C99?

Comment: Sim, mas talvez alguém discorde porque negativou a resposta.

Comment: Ops, foi sem querer.