# Qual a versão mais recente e estável do HTTP?

Tags: http

Gostaria de saber a versão mais recente do HTTP e a mais estável e usada dele.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ao contrário do que está imaginando, HTTP é só uma [especificação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111284/101) e não um software, então não cabe falar em estabilidade, qualquer versão de uma especificação é estável porque não muda e não pode ter *bugs*. A atual é a 2.0 e não espere uma versão mais nova tão cedo, não muda toda hora, mas há uma discussão para o [HTTP 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/3) o que pode não mudar a API.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).