# O que é HTTP/3? Ele substituirá o HTTP/2?

Tags: http

Na pergunta

[Qual a versão mais recente e estável do HTTP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/407931/5878)

Foi citado a existência da versão 3 do protocolo HTTP. Essa nova especificação do protocolo visa substituir a versão HTTP/2? O que ela faz que essas versões anteriores não fazem e quais os problemas que ela busca resolver?

No HTTP/2 tivemos a possibilidade de fazer o envio de conteúdo via PUSH do servidor para o cliente sem requisição e reduzir redundância entre os cabeçalhos de múltiplas requisições. Quais são as principais características do HTTP/3?

Comment: Pelo que li o que muda é apenas o protocolo "base", no caso no 3 seria o [***QUIC***](https://www.chromium.org/quic) (pelo que li é UDP e não TCP, aparentemente desenvolvido pela Google). Claro que tem detalhamentos e uma ou outra mudança. Vou aguardar as respostas :)

Answer (score 1):

Tanto o HTTP 1.0 e 1.1 quanto o HTTP/2 são protocolos de rede de alto nível, que funcionam sobre o protocolo TCP que é de mais baixo nível.

Imagine que você está falando com uma pessoa pelo telefone, HTTP seria os sons que vocês estão emitindo, TCP seria os sinais elétricos que os telefones estão enviando um para o outro.

A versão HTTP/3 (anteriormente chamada de HTTP sobre QUIC) nada mais é do que uma versão levemente modificada do HTTP/2 para funcionar sobre o protocolo QUIC ao invés do protocolo TCP.

O protocolo TCP foi criado para garantir a entrega dos dados enviados, para isso ele usa algumas técnicas que acabam impactando a performance do HTTP/2. Principalmente o seu multiplexing, que é quando dois ou mais fluxos de dados (ex: dois arquivos .js) são transmitidos ao mesmo tempo dentro do mesmo canal de comunicação.

O QUIC foi criado pelo Google para ser um substituto mais leve e rápido para o TCP. Trocar o TCP pelo QUIC permite que a página seja carregada mais rápido e usando menos banda. Isso já acontece quando você acessa os servidores do Google usando o Chrome, pois a comunicação é feita com o QUIC.

Em outras palavras, HTTP/3 nada mais é do que padronizar o HTTP sobre QUIC para que todos os navegadores e servidores possar se comunicar mais rápido sem nenhum problema de compatibilidade.

Por enquanto ele ainda é uma proposta, mas dada a melhora de performance, a economia de banda e o suporte que o QUIC está recebendo de grandes empresas da Web como Google, Facebook, Mozilla, Opera, Cloudflare e outras, é bem provável que ele será adotado.